# Runpath Search Paths Reason: The bundle “MySecondFramework” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources

Tags: swift, carthage

I am using Carthage.
while running the unit test cases getting the error, The bundle “MySecondFramework” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources

Answer (score 0):

in test target under build setting -> runPath add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS`